# Android Studio add Fragment in FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm just getting into Android development and I followed the standard guide for creating a fragment on the official android developer documentation website. However, when I try to add my simple fragment to the fragment container, the add() method claims that the passed parameter of my Fragment class is incorrect.

This is my onCreate() method of my main activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container_view, ChatFragment.class, null)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

and this is my Fragment class:

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {
    public ChatFragment() {
        super(R.layout.chat_layout);
    }
}
```

The compiler error I'm getting is "Required Type: Fragment, Provided: Class", although I just copied the code from the official documentation website. Maybe something changed since they wrote this, but I couldn't find a solution so far.

What I'm trying to do in general is that I've got my bottom navigation bar and depending on which item I click on, another fragment should be displayed, the upper fragment in my code being the "standard" view when starting the app.

Comment: Use `new ChatFragment()`

Comment: Then it says "Provided: ChatFragment"

Comment: Check the parameter list for what you need to pass  to the method with Ctrl+P please

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container_view, new ChatFragment(), null)
                    .commit();
```

Comment: I already tried that, but then it says "Required Type: Fragment, Provided: ChatFragment"

Comment: what are the imports in your CharFragment ?

Comment: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment, androidx.annotation.Nullable and android.os.Bundle

Answer (score 0):

Try below things

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container_view,new ChatFragment(),"ChatFragment").commit();
```

In Chat Fragment instead of constructor try to inflate in onCreateView

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_layout, container, false);
}
```